# While and Break statements for python 2.7

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, break

I'm rather new to python and so I was wondering if someone could help me figure out my while loop and break statements.

I can get it to either continue or break but never both.

I have researched the subject and found that all examples that I find tend to be for numbers and so on or that the information supplied is just not clicking for me.

So any help would be appreciated.

## This program is designed to work out your weekly wages.

while True:

```
Hours_Worked = int(raw_input("How many hours have you worked this week?:\n"))#This line of code allows the user to input the amount of hours they have worked in whole numbers only.


Hourly_Rate = float(raw_input("What is your hourly rate?:\n" u"\u00A3"))#This line of code allows the user to input their hourly rate of pay in floating numbers to wither a whole or decimal points.


Tax = int(raw_input("What is your current Tax rate?:\n" u"\u0025"))#This line of code allows the user to input their tax rate.


Nat = int(raw_input("What is your National Insurance rate?:\n" u"\u0025"))#This line of code allows the user to input their National Insurance rate.


Total_Weekly_Pay = (Hours_Worked*Hourly_Rate)#This line of code works out the weekly pay before deductions.


Total_Weekly_Pay_After_Deductions = Total_Weekly_Pay - (Tax*Total_Weekly_Pay/100) - (Nat*Total_Weekly_Pay/100)# This line of code works out the weekly pay after deductions. The Tax and National Insurance rate are worked out by multiplying and then dividing.


print "Your Total weekly pay before deductions is\n" u"\u00A3%5.2f" %(Total_Weekly_Pay)#This line of code prints out the weekly pay before deductions to the floating points of 5.2.


print "Your Total weekly pay after Tax and National Insurance deductions is\n" u"\u00A3%5.2f" %(Total_Weekly_Pay_After_Deductions)#This line of code prints out the weekly pay after deductions to the floating points of 5.2.

cont = raw_input("Would you like to try again? (yes/no)\n")
if cont == "no":
    print "Goodbye"
    break
```

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string, not a `True`/`False`.

Comment: Also what's up with your empty print statements?

Comment: whenever I added "\n" to the end of an input line it would stop working so I went with the empty print to make it less cluttered for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking if should be:

```
if cont == "":
```

Or a value you tell the user for exit, so:

```
cont = raw_input("Would you like to try again?  (Yes/No")
if cont == "No":
```

Comment: might want to explain what raw_input returns and why comparing different objects doesn't work

Comment: ok iv tried your suggestion and managed to get it to work, also tided up the empty print options and so on.

Comment: @MooingRawr had done that in an edit but lost connection :S Darren, basically raw_input returns a string, which even if empty is still existant.